Need whole system to be running on sim time
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and ros2 humble. When using nav2, my robot follows its set path, but midway through gets an error then spins and comes to a stop. I believe its because of this line in the error:
[planner_server-15] [ERROR] [1715892386.509665059] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 274.088000 but the earliest data is at time 275.472000, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]
This error indicates my system is using sim and wall time. I went through all my launch files and set use_sim_time to true, and I used commands to check all of my nodes use_sim_time params and they're all set to true, except this one:
ros2 param get launch_ros_395369 use_sim_time
Boolean value is: False

it seems that launch_ros_# is a node with generated numbers at the end, and I don't know how to set that to true

I'm having a similar problem
